# Compare two array lists of objects by property value

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have two array lists of objects, I need to compare them by the property value and to return unique. Object has two properties, question and answer, only the objects from list one with unique question should be returned.

```
        *faq(question, answer)*

        List<faq> one = new ArrayList<>();
        one.add(new faq("question 1", "answer 1"));
        one.add(new faq("question 2", "answer 2"));
        one.add(new faq("question 3", "answer 3"));
        
        List<faq> two = new ArrayList<>();
        two.add(new faq("question 4", "answer 4"));
        two.add(new faq("question 5", "answer 5"));
        two.add(new faq("question 1", "answer 6"));
        two.add(new faq("question 7", "answer 7"));
        two.add(new faq("question 8", "answer 8"));
```

From this code here I want to get objects from list one with questions 2 and 3 since only those two are not contained in list two

Comment: Does the class `faq` implement/overrides the `equals` (and hashcode) method?

Comment: Are you looking for `List#removeAll` method? [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) If you want to leave list `one` without changes, just copy it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the `equals()` and `hashCode()` in `Faq.java`

- **Faq.java**

```
    import java.util.Objects;
    import java.util.StringJoiner;
    
    public class Faq {
        private String questions;
        private String answer;
    
        public Faq(final String questions, final String answer) {
            this.questions = questions;
            this.answer = answer;
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public boolean equals(final Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            final Faq faq = (Faq) o;
            return questions.equals(faq.questions);
        }
    
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(questions);
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return new StringJoiner(", ", Faq.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
                    .add("questions='" + questions + "'")
                    .toString();
        }
    }
```

- **Main.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Faq> one = new ArrayList<>();
        one.add(new Faq("question 1", "answer 1"));
        one.add(new Faq("question 2", "answer 2"));
        one.add(new Faq("question 3", "answer 3"));

        List<Faq> two = new ArrayList<>();
        two.add(new Faq("question 4", "answer 4"));
        two.add(new Faq("question 5", "answer 5"));
        two.add(new Faq("question 1", "answer 6"));
        two.add(new Faq("question 7", "answer 7"));
        two.add(new Faq("question 8", "answer 8"));

        one.removeAll(two);
        System.out.println(one);
    }
}
```

- **Output**

```
    [Faq[questions='question 2'], Faq[questions='question 3']]
```

Comment: Worth noting that it modifies list `one`. If OP wants to leave `one` as is, he should copy it first.